# Conditional IO methods based on ValueProvider option

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am running into few issues migrating following logic in my dataflow to templates. Without rewriting the existing IO methods, is there a way to maintain this functionality?

1. Conditionally reading from different sources depending on the option parameter. (ie specifying io source in the options)
2. Conditionally writing to a source depending on the option parameter. (Ie dryrun using file dump instead of db)

Comment: What is your programming language for Apache Beam SDK?  According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#pipeline-io-and-runtime-parameters) some of I/O connectors accept `ValueProvider` parameters.

Comment: Java. Both the IOs I am using accepts ValueProvider but I am trying to conditionallu call one or the other

Comment: Can you share the original pipeline code that you want to create the template?

Comment: also, is this Java or Python?